# Retrieving entire collection then add it into a dictionary

Tags: objcmongodb

I can retrieve a single entry from a collection in a mongodb but I cannot retrieve the entire collection. After I retrieve the entire collection I would like to put it into a dictionary. Retrieving the entire collection should be simple. I have tested the various commands I would use in the shell to accomplish the task, but all are unsuccessful once translated into objective-c.

```
   //Message Retrieval
    BSONDocument *resultDoc = [collection findAllWithError:&error];
    NSDictionary *result = [BSONDecoder decodeDictionaryWithDocument:resultDoc];
    NSLog(@"fetch result: %@", result);
```

Comment: @noa I understand how to fetch just one entry with `findOneWithPredicate:predicate`, however is there any way just to do a collection.find() so that it returns all of the items under the collection? I have looked through ObjCMongodb's functionality's and nothing caught my eye that was able to do such a thing.

Comment: Yes, it's `-findAllWithError:`.

Comment: @noa tried using this (updated code above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-findAllWithError:` returns an array of documents:

```
NSArray *results = [collection findAllWithError:&error];
for (BSONDocument *resultDoc in results) {
    NSDictionary *result = [BSONDecoder decodeDictionaryWithDocument:resultDoc];
    NSLog(@"fetch result: %@", result);
}
```